# How to get last modification date timestamp in "DIR /S /B" result?

Tags: windows, command-line, search, dir

In the early days of Windows (3.1, Windows 95) there was a wonderful feature, called "Find", which could be used for finding files on your computer.

Some *** has decided to remove this feature and "integrate" it in the regular Windows explorer.
Although it has most probably been done with the best intentions, in many cases it's not working: I type `file:*.bak` and when I'm lucky (mostly I'm not) my computer searches for a `*.bak` file.

So, I've decided to go for the good old commandline, and when I need to search for a file, I go to the major directory and type `dir /S /B *.bak`, and it's working like a charm!

But ... the last modification date is not shown, which makes it quite difficult to see which is the latest bak-file in my list.

Does anybody know how to add the last modification date to a `Dir /S /B` result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/B` option, which is the option to *hide* the last modification date (as well as the other frills besides the file name).

Recent Windows versions include `forfiles.exe`, which can recursively find files by name and/or age and run some command for each result. Conveniently it supports date/time substitutions for the command:

```
forfiles /s /m *.c /c "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime @path"
```

PowerShell can give you more flexibility; its default output is similar to that of Cmd's `dir`:

```
dir -recurse *.c
```

but behind the scenes it's object-based (until it gets converted to text for display on screen), so you could use `... | Select-Object` to output a single flat table with specific properties (disabling the 'dir'-style per-directory tables):

```
dir -rec *.c | select LastWriteTime,FullName
```

...or create your own output using `... | ForEach-Object {...}`

```
dir -r *.c | % { echo "$($_.LastWriteTime) -- $($_.FullName)" }
```